# Can't turn on WiFi on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, wireless

I've freshly installed Ubuntu 16.04 after running 16.10 (I reinstalled the system due to some bugs I had before) and I can't turn on my WiFi. After opening network settings and clicking on the on/off button, the slider just goes back to off. I also can't click on Enable WiFi. After opening Additional Drivers in Software&Update, I have only one, unknown driver, nothing for broadband (this was also the case with my previous Ubuntu, when WiFi worked properly)
Running lspci | grep -i net results in:

```
01:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 3160 (rev cb)
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller (rev 07)

rfkill list all shows: 
0: Toshiba Bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
```

rfkill unblock all doesn't work.
Help?

```
lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; dmesg | grep iwl outputs:
01:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 3160 [8086:08b3] (rev cb)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless AC 3160 [8086:8170]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi
[   12.499919] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: loaded firmware version 17.352738.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[   13.136326] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 3160, REV=0x164
[   13.138894] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[   13.139197] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[   13.195442] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'iwl-mvm-rs'
[   14.840691] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0 wlp1s0: renamed from wlan0
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; dmesg | grep iwl` terminal command.

Comment: All is OK with the drivers. There is a hardware switch somewhere.

Comment: I've been pressing the button multiple times, nothing happens. ..

Comment: Check the BIOS.

Comment: May we also see: `lsmod`?